# Otorgar permiso de geolocalización a un webview en una app MAUI

Tags: blazor, maui

Tengo una app en Blazor que en algunas páginas necesita obtener la geolocalización del cliente. En todos los navegadores que he probado va bien, sin ningún problema. La cuestión es que quiero embeber la aplicación en un webview en MAUI ya que al ser responsiva me serviría como app en Android. En el manifiesto de la app está reflejado el permiso. Cuando se inicia la aplicación se pide acceso a la ubicación y aunque el usuario se la da cuando va a hacer una llamada a la petición de geolocalización falla. El error que devuelve la función javascript es "Permiso denegado para obtener la ubicación" .

He estado debugeando y en la primera página el permiso está concedido.

¿Alguna idea de cómo debo gestionar los permisos de geolocalización?

Gracias.

He intentado añadir los permisos, configurar el manifiesto...

Comment: Tal cual está la pregunta, sin código, las chances de obtener respuestas son bajas. Edita y agrega todo mínimo necesario para que cualquiera pueda reproducir tu escenario, de este modo las chances de obtener respuesta, aumentan. Saludos.